# $scope vs this performance

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-scope

Difference between [this vs $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers) is clearly answered in this question. One of the projects I am working in, Our senior guy is promoting `this` over `$scope` arguing it provides better performance.

I tried to find any evidence for the same but official angular documents do have very limited information on this matter.

Can any one please explain

1. Is `this` provide better performance over `$scope` (provided I don't use `$watch` etc)
2. If yes for what exact reasons ? is the performance improvement significant enough to change an existing application using `$scope` to `this` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: please read question clearly, Am not asking for deference I am asking some thing else

Comment: refer this: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Stylistically it is better to use `this` than `$scope` as that way when you do use a `$watch` or similar it is a giant heads up as that controller takes in `$scope` for a reason, otherwise you tend to ignore it is there. Also, people tend to use things like `$scope.$apply` and similar if it's available - they'll find "better" ways if it's not. Performance wise, probably no benefit at all.

Comment: I am not sure about performance, but definetily $scope is a syntactic sugar  over native this. Now a days Angular team is promoting controller as which uses this instead of $scope. The real benefit is when you migrate from angular 1.* to 2.0. 

Other benefit includes decoupling controller from the framework, so that you can test the controller out of angular context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AngularJS performance is affected by the number of binding the currently loaded view (page) is using and the watches that you setup manually using `$watch`.
All this binding only work on properties declared on $scope.

This means if you are not binding a property to view or not watching it, you better not declare it on the $scope (also called avoiding scope pollution).

Coming to `this`, as explained in the SO post `this` has different context when invoked by Angular (such as in case of ng-click) and when controller is created.

So anything that you declare on `this` (when referring to controller) technically cannot be bound to the view as it is not declared on the scope.

But Angular came up with a `controller as` syntax where it allow us to use properties and method over the controller object. In such scenario properties declared over controller are bound in the view using `ctrl.prop` syntax.
Internally Angular does something like this when you do `ng-controller='HomeController as ctrl'`

`$scope.ctrl=this`

Which basically means Angular is attaching the complete controller object to the `$scope` and hence binding with controller properties work.

So only thing that matter in terms of performance is the number of binding being watched.

Comment: so in short there is no performance benefit of `this` over `$scope`!?

Comment: As mentioned performance is defined by the number of binding in view, not directly by `this` or `$scope`. If you define a number of properties on scope and never use it, then it does not affect the performance.

Comment: In the case, isint it better to use `$scope` instead of `this`? If I understand correctly, if `controller as` syntax exposes the entire `this` to `$scope`, doesnt that cause more `$scope` pollution that the method where we only declare `$scope` in controller when we need it?

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs uses both of them interchangeably so there's no difference regarding the performance.

But using `this` should be lower performance (not even so lower) than the `$scope` as `this` creates a new instance of the object.

But really using `this` is more elegant way as:

- More contextual (for eg. items.name than name)
- Can be used nested controller easily without any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have watches it **shouldn't** create a performance barrier.

In my opinion, you should **not** have any "this" methods\properties on your `controller`.
A `controller` is the view's best friend and should only have relevant properties on it. 
A relevant property is a property that you are going to bind inside your view (properties, functions etc.).

All your "this" properties should probably be on a `service`.